# Login system does not work

Tags: php, mysql, apache, authentication

I have made alogin system, but it does not seem to work on my clients PC only...

It used to work for years but it suddenly just stopped last night.

I have tried to clear cache, cookies, used 3 different browsers she gets the login success which means cookies are set, and it's loggedin, when she is redirected to bypass the login screen she is simply asked to login again, in a loop over and over again...

I tried to login from my pc using same password, same username, it logs me in perfectly fine...

I have run out of options as to what it could be...

She is using an apple (mac) computer, and I tried it on safari, chrome,firefox.

I can confirm that cookies are enabled, and cleared I just don't know what else I can check to debug the script as this is only a problem on one PC only and it just stopped over night with no modifications or anything... unless there is a server update issue by host provider.

I am asking for any help where I can look into fixing it, as I dont believe there is anything wrong with the login system itself. but the pc of my client.

Comment: How are we supposed to diagnose the problem without seeing any code…?

Comment: Tell the client to install FF for Mac and see if it works there. If it works, then you can reset the settings of Safari and try again in Safari.

Comment: Like I said, its nothing wrong with the code as this works on every other PC other than hers.... ( I used ff,chrome,safari) Its her PC that something must have happened...(if you asking for codes you obviously haven't read the question) I wish I cud -1 you :@ lol

Comment: maybe his/her browser doesn't save data such as cookies, or get cleared everytime he/she closes the browser. if this works for 10000 people and fails to work for one, well that one has a problem, not the website.

Comment: Thats what, I said :) ok I asked else where and it seems that could be a cookie reset or auto clear or something with anti virus or security software, she has a MAC and I dont know how check what it could be :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the server's access log files to see if there's an actual POST request from her PC to the server (and what status code it returned). Other than that, I would suggest that you connect to her PC using teamviewer or something similar and see for yourself

Comment: I used team viewer, clearned cache, everything, cookies, closed browser, restarted PC,router, I believe there is an ISP problem, this is one a kind problem,(she is computer illiterate) which makes this that much harder, I guess it's either some DNS problem, or some other complicated things coz she is the only one person on the world that has this problem... cheers for the help.